# Calculate the probability of a record

Tags: probability

A box contains $n$ tickets numbered from $1$ to $n$.
We say that there is a record at the $k$th selection when the number selected is strictly greater than all the previous ones.

We note $R_k$ the event : "there is a record at the $k$th selection". (obviously, $R_1 =1$)

Calculate $\mathbb{P}(R_k)$.

I don't know how to start...

Comment: You could start with cases of small $n$, for example $n=3$ or $n=4$.

Comment: I tried with $n=3$ and I found : $R_1 = 1 ; R_2 = 1/2 ; R_3 = 1/6$ But I don't really understand, I just count all the possibilities... I also tried with $n=4$ but... don't see how to do that...

Comment: It is equivalent to say that you randomly select $k$ tickets out first and randomly order them. There is a record at the $k$th selection if and only if the maximum among these $k$ tickets is located at the $k$th position.

Comment: Are you French ?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you guessed it because of the strange translation.

Comment: Perhaps this is of some use? https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DistributionOfRecords/#more